# Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

Tags: devops, apache2, vps

Hi everyone I am new to devOps, I configured an Apache server on my vps, but a few days later I encountered this problem the Apache server no longer responds and when I try to restart it I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJivG.png)
Please i need help

I'm trying to restart the server with this command `apachectl -k restart` or `systemctl restart apache2` but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: What is the result of `netstat -anp|grep LIST|grep :80` (run as root)